# C++11 default class member initialization with initializer list , simultaneously

Tags: c++, c++11

Can someone point me please, to a corresponding paragraph of the C++ standard, or maybe can provide some explanation why my code does not compile if I uncomment the text `({123})`?

Generally speaking I understand what something wrong with usage of default member initialization and initialization via initializer list, but I can't refer to exact reasons.

```
enum class MY: int
{
    A = 1
};

struct abc
{
    int a;/*{123};*/  //compilation failed if uncommented
    MY m;
};

abc a = {1, MY::A};
```

Compiler error, in case of uncommented text:

> error: could not convert ‘{1, A}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘abc’

Comment: In C++11 the usage of NSDMI makes your struct not an aggregate. In C++14 this has changed iirc

Comment: Yup, so if you compile with `-std=c++14`, you are all good.

Comment: If that's the case, it deserves another answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The below syntax:

```
abc a = {1, MY::A};
```

is a list-initialization which may perform differently depending on the type being initialized. Without the non-static data member initializer (`/*{123};*/`), your struct is an aggregate and the case falls under [[dcl.init.list]/p3](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#3.4):

> - Otherwise, if `T` is an aggregate, aggregate initialization is performed.

However, to be an aggregate type, the following conditions must be met in C++11:

> An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided constructors (12.1), **no brace-or-equal-initializers for non-static data members (9.2)**, no private or protected non-static data members (Clause 11), no base classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3).

That is, the usage of NSDMI (non-static data member initialization) breaks the above set of rules, and as a result, an instance of this type can no longer be list-initialized.

This rule has changed in C++14, and the current wording reads [[dcl.init.aggr]/p1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#1):

> An aggregate is an array or a class with
>
> - (1.1) no user-provided, explicit, or inherited constructors ([class.ctor]),
> - (1.2) no private or protected non-static data members ([class.access]),
> - (1.3) no virtual functions, and
> - (1.4) no virtual, private, or protected base classes ([class.mi]).
>
> [ *Note*: Aggregate initialization does not allow accessing protected and private base class' members or constructors. — *end note* ]